# Text overflows into other div when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I have multiple divs that are stacked in a vertical fashion but when I resize the window the text from one div overflows into other divs and all text on the page becomes unreadable because they are all overlaying eachother. Is it possible to make it so that when the window is resized instead of divs overflowing into eachother they instead expand their height so they are stacked on top of eachother?

Here's my CSS

```
.middle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  position: relative;
  top: 74px;
  margin: auto;
}

.middle .portSection {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.middle .portSection .left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0px;
}

.middle .portSection .right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0px;
}

.middle .portSection .left .description {
  position: relative;

  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

".middle" is what holds all of the divs, ".middle .portSection .left .description" is the p element that is overflowing

Comment: You need to remove the fixed height of each div, so that it will automatically increase its height based on the content on resize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your css seems redundant here. By using position absolute you are removing the elements from the document flow.

I recommend you instead use flexbox as it's much better designed to handle this type of layout.

```css
.middle .portSection {
  display: flex;
  height: 450px;
}

.middle .portSection .left {
  background: #f88;
  flex:1;
}

.middle .portSection .right {
  background: #88f;
  flex:1;
}

.middle .portSection .left .description {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <div class="portSection">
    <div class="left">

    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue nisi pellentesque, consectetur tellus sit amet, convallis sem. Pellentesque in ante mauris. Quisque sodales ex sagittis, eleifend tellus eget, iaculis risus. Aenean imperdiet risus
        eu lacus varius, non auctor tortor vehicula. Phasellus sed augue in neque auctor tempor. Cras bibendum mauris velit, id rhoncus diam fermentum eget. Proin quis condimentum nisl. Fusce consequat augue ullamcorper, ornare felis quis, volutpat mauris.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still get the same issue of text overflowing into other divs

Comment: That's because of your existing styling. Remove it. There's is no need, in the code you posted, to have any position attributes.

Comment: Changed everything to use flexbox and then changed the height of the portSection to "fit-content" and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aaron glad you sorted it. Flex box is much more "flexible" and a good standard to use moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your styles

```
.left .description  {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Or,

```
.left .description p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.middle .portSection .left .description {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

It should work :)

Comment: Flex box is better yes

Answer (score 0):

```
.middle {
  height: fit-content; 
  width: 65%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  margin: auto;
}

.middle .portSection {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.middle .portSection .left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0px;
}

.middle .portSection .right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0px;
}

.middle .portSection .left .description {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

if this does not work, then please share your HTML also.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you want to explain but I some what figure out that you want to show two paragraphs side by side in middle. Right?

the problem caused because you user position absolute and relative as the div scale full display after adding position absolute and it is very difficult to figure out relative position for all child div if you are not well familiar with position properties. In this case I will suggest you to use flex-box. It will make your work easy as below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    *
    {
        padding: 0px;
    }
.middle {
  display: flex;
  width: 65%;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}

.middle .portSection {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.middle .portSection .left {
    background: grey;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.middle .portSection .right {
    background: grey;
    display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.middle .portSection .left .description {
    background: skyblue;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.middle .portSection .right .description {
    background: skyblue;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="portSection">
            <div class="left">
                <p class="description">Here is a div1 sddfsdafdsfdsf ds dsfds s fdsaf sdf dsf sdfds fdsf d fdf dsf ds fdsfds fdsf dsa f dsa fda</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portSection">
            <div class="right">
                <p class="description">Here is a div2 sddfsdafdsfdsf ds dsfds s fdsaf sdf dsf sdfds fdsf d fdf dsf ds fdsfds fdsf dsa f dsa fda</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```